# Where should I put original image like `psd` and `xcf` in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there conventional place for original images like `psd` or `xcf` files in rails project?

I want to follow the convention if it exists.

Comment: Those don't belong in the Rails project at all. You should have them archived/version-controlled elsewhere.

Comment: ok, then I'd put all files where I want. Thanks.

Comment: I sort of disagree here. We've kept our PSDs under rails/creative/ folder because we want all our creative sources to be versioned and branched at the same time that the Rails app gets branched. We usually make modification to creative and rails app within the same branch, thus it's important for us that PSDs and rails code are related.

Comment: Versioning binary files (like PSDs or XCFs) is rather bad idea. I would preffer using any cloud storage, like Dropbox or Egnyte for stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no convention for where you place your project sources and other files.
But I too see why it's important to keep them together, and versioned in git.
I created a `resources` folder under my rails projects' root folder and place them there, i.e. `your_app_root_folder/resources`.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment above, we find very helpful to keep everything in one centralized place, so  all resources get branched at the same time. We usually add these additional folders to each Rails app:

```
myapp/resources/
----------------
   |___/creative = all creative resources for the site (i.e. PSDs, AIs, PNGs, etc.)
   |___/docs     = all documentation related to the project   
   |___/ux       = UX designs and US related stuff
```

I've explained our approach in [Where to store additional Rails project files?](http://demisx.github.io/rails/2014/03/02/where-store-additional-rails-project-files.html) blog post